# Passing variable type as function parameter

Tags: c, gcc

Is it possible to pass variable type as part of a function parameter, e.g.:

```
void foo(varType type)
{
  // Cast to global static
  unsigned char bar;
  bar = ((type *)(&static_array))->member;
}
```

I remember it has something to do with GCC's `typeof` and using macros?

Comment: Not in standard C.  Maybe in GCC, if you are (un)lucky.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't do that for a function, because then it needs to know the types of the arguments (and any other symbols the function uses) to generate working machine code. You could try a macro like:

```
#define foo(type_t) ({ \
    unsigned char bar; \
    bar = ((type_t*)(&static_array))->member; \
    ... \
    })
```

Answer (score 50):

You could make an enum for all different types possible, and use a switch to make the dereferencing:

```
typedef enum {
    CHAR,
    INT,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE
} TYPE;

void foo(TYPE t, void* x){
    switch(t){
        case CHAR:
            (char*)x;
            break;
        case INT:
            (int*)x;
            break;
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi hugomg, I'm sorry but I don't understand the alternative. Could you elaborate a little? Thanks :-)

Comment: I just realized that the alternative doesn't really work as written... so I deleted it. But the basic idea I originally had was to code things in "object oriented" style and use subtype polymorphism to do the branching instead of a switch statement.

Comment: for me it's work only with typedef: "typedef enum {
    CHAR,
    INT,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE
} TYPE;"

Answer (score 8):

Eh, *of course **you can***. Just use a macro like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define swap(type, foo, bar) ({type tmp; tmp=foo; foo=bar; bar=tmp;})

int main() {
  int a=3, b=0;
  swap(int, a, b); //  check it out!

  printf("a=%d, b=%d \n", a, b); // a=0, b=3
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't actually pass a type to a function here, but create new code for every time you use it.

Comment: To avoid doubt: `({...})` is a "statement expression", which is a GCC extension and not standard C.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how you could do this in the general case, given that C is a [statically typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing).

The compiler needs to know at compile time what the type of `type *` is in order to be able to  generate the reference to `->member`.

Comment: Dont be so negative have a more can do attitude ;)

Comment: It is possible with quite extensive C macros - see this very short type-generic thing in Boost PP (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/examples/array_arithmetic.c) or the Perl Data Language (https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL - disclosure: I am current maintainer of this 26-year-old project).