# Is there any way to avoid repeated code when you're casting a void pointer in a function based on a switch?

Tags: c

Based on the answer to the question [Passing variable type as function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658593/passing-variable-type-as-function-parameter):

I could write something like this:

```
enum {
    TYPEA,
    TYPEB,
    TYPEC,
    TYPED
} TYPE;

void foo(TYPE t, void* x){
    switch(t){
        case TYPEA:
            struct A* y = (struct A*)x;
                            //do something with a member named "next"   
            break;
        case TYPEB:
            struct B* y = (struct B*)x;
                            //do something with a member named "next" 
         ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid rewriting the "something with a member named next" multiple times?

We are assuming that "next" in A and B are not in the same relative memory position in each struct.

Comment: Have you considered using a macro?

Comment: does the `next` member at least have the same type in all structs ?

Comment: thats the solution which was accepted in the referred question. I guess he doesn't want to use it.

Comment: You could move the *do something with member xxx* part into a (static) function, which takes a void* pointer as an argument. NOTE: if the pointers point to (almost similar) structs with a common "prefix", this construct is known as a "smart union"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the items of the enum aren't given custom numbers, you can do a compact version of a switch-statement, by using function pointers.

```
enum {
    TYPEA,
    TYPEB,
    TYPEC,
    TYPED,

    TYPE_N // number of enum items
} TYPE;


typedef void(*type_func_t)(void*);



static void TYPEA_specific (void* x) 
{
  struct A* y = x;

  // specific stuff related to TYPEA here

  do_something_with_next(y->next);
}

static void TYPEB_specific (void* x) 
{
  struct B* y = x;

  // specific stuff related to TYPEB here

  do_something_with_next(y->next);
}



static const type_func_t TYPE_HANDLER [TYPE_N] = 
{
  TYPEA_specific,
  TYPEB_specific
  ...
};


inline void foo (TYPE t, void* x)
{
  TYPE_HANDLER[t](x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define POLYCAST_AB(etype, target, member) \
  *((etype) == TYPEA ? &((struct A *)(target))->member :  \
    (etype) == TYPEB ? &((struct B *)(target))->member : 0)

enum TYPE {
   TYPEA,
   TYPEB
};

struct A {
   int next;
} a = {42};

struct B {
   int i;
   int next;
} b = {43, 44};

static void foo(enum TYPE t, void *x) {
   POLYCAST_AB(t, x, next) += 100;  // <-- most other answers can't do this
   printf("next=%d\n", POLYCAST_AB(t, x, next));
}

int main(void) {
   foo(TYPEA, &a);   
   foo(TYPEB, &b);   
   return 0;
}
```

If you don't need an lvalue, you can omit the extra `*` and `&` in the macro definition (and also omit the assumption that the `next` all have the same type).

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have dynamic look-up of structure members, of course.

The solution that will save the most keystrokes is probably to use a macro.

Also, there's no point in casting the pointer when converting from `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

In each `case`, you can take the address of `next` with `&y.next` and then either pass it to a function or transfer control to code that uses the pointer to do something with `next`. This presumes that `next` has the same type in each `struct`, although it may be in different locations.

Here are three examples:

```
// Example 0:  Functional call.
switch(t)
{
    case TYPEA:
        MyFunction(&(struct A *)x->next);
        break;
    case TYPEB:
        MyFunction(&(struct B *)x->next);
        break;
}

// Example 1: Code after the switch.
TypeOfNext *next;
switch(t)
{
    case TYPEA:
        next = &(struct A *)x->next;
        break;
    case TYPEB:
        next = &(struct B *)x->next;
        break;
}
… code that uses next…

// Example 2: Code in the switch, with goto.
switch(t)
{
    TypeOfNext *next;
    case TYPEA:
        next = &(struct A *)x->next;
        goto common;
    case TYPEB:
        next = &(struct B *)x->next;
    common:
        … code that uses next…
        break;
}
```