# Passing variable type as a function parameter in rust?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to pass a primitive type (such as `i32`) as a function argument. 
For example, I want to read the user input and store it in a vector of my choosing with a function

```
use std::io;
fn main()
{
get_vectorized_line(i32) ;  
}

fn get_vectorized_line(expected_type: type)->Vec<expected_type>{
    let mut line_content=String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut line_content).expect("Could not read line");
    let vectorized_line: Vec<expected_type> = line_content.trim().split(" ").
    map(|s| s.parse().expect("Could not parse")).collect();
    return vectorized_line;
}
```

responds with 
`expected value, found builtin type i32` when the function is called.

I know it is possible to pass types as arguments in Python, (and not in standard [C without using macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658593/passing-variable-type-as-function-parameter)).

I believe I could be using [generic functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/gen_fn.html) to do what I want. But I wanted clarity on this topic

Comment: Rust [does not have reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36416773/1233251). There isn't a type for values representing types in Rust.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have a suggestion on how I should go about this task? With generic functions?

Comment: This seem to be exactly [what generics are for](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=87670d19da4432cb8eae3d49b6e76f9e). Any reason not to use them?

Comment: I was not very familiar with generic functions. Thanks for the example code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really like the syntax of passing a type as an argument:

```
macro_rules! gvl {
    ($t:ty) => {{
        let mut content = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut content).unwrap();
        content.trim().split(' ').map(
            |s| s.parse::<$t>().unwrap()
        ).collect::<Vec<$t>>()
    }}
}
```

And tah-dah:

```
let _ = gvl!(i32);
```

No external type annotations required!

---

#### Please don't actually do that

Use first class types with a special syntax that is (almost) what you want:

```
let _ = gvl::<i32>();
```

```
fn gvl<T: FromStr>() -> Vec<T> where <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug {
    let mut content=String::new();
    stdin().read_line(&mut content).unwrap();
    content.trim().split(' ').map(
        |s| s.parse().unwrap()
    ).collect()
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you recommend against using generic functions in your answer?

Comment: I _do_ recommend using generic functions (2nd example); I _do not_ recommend using macros. The generic function is more easily type/error checked and conveys your intention much more clearly than the macro solution.

Comment: Both are frankly ugly as hell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics on return types. Here the generic T has to implement FromStr (because it is parsed from str) and must be displayable (for the eventual panic message).

```rust
use std::io;

fn get_vectorized_line<T: std::str::FromStr>()->Vec<T> where <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug {
    let mut line_content=String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut line_content).expect("Could not read line");
    line_content.trim().split(' ').map(|s| s.parse().unwrap()).collect()
}

fn main()
{
    let vectorized_line: Vec<i32> = get_vectorized_line() ;  
}
```